# Setting up Windows Server 2012 Cluster for distributed computing with Matlab

Tags: cluster, windows

My aim is to setup `Matlab` properly for distributed computing on many physical nodes.

**What have I done?**

I have installed `Windows Server 2012 r2` on my local network **server**, installed `Failover Cluster tools`. Also I have installed `Windows Server 2012 r2` on **two connected computers** in our local network. I have joined them into **cluster** using `Failover Cluster Management`.
It was fine, but then I installed `Matlab` on **server** and tried to find my own Cluster using `Parallel Computing->Discover Clusters` toolbox. So I recieved an error:

> Could not contact any MJS lookup service. You may not have started
>   MJS, or multicast protocols may be failing on your network. If you are
>   certain that MJS is running, specify the host in your profile.

I have found **nothing** in the Web about how to properly setup cluster using Windows Server 2012 Failover Clustering tools and then use it in Matlab.

Could you help me please? What should I do?

P.S. Sorry for my English

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As background, Windows Failover Clustering is definitely the wrong technology for what you want. Right there in the name, it says "failover". It does not do distributed or compute clustering. Full stop - you're barking up the wrong tree.

You should read up on Matlab's own documentation. Always read the vendor's stuff. [MJS is a Matlab software component](http://www.mathworks.com/help/mdce/configure-parallel-computing-products-for-an-mjs.html). If you didn't install it, of course it won't find it.

You could instead use Windows HPC, which is their High Performance Computing package, which is an entirely different type of clustering from Failover Clustering. You need to download and configure it.

FYI, Server 2012 is not on the supported list for Matlab clustering. 
http://www.mathworks.com/support/sysreq/current_release/index.html

So, pick one. Windows HPC (preferably on Server 2008 according to the vendor), or Matlab's own MJS.

Answer (score 0):

Reading through the documentation for the various types of Matlab clusters, no where does it talk about using Windows Failover Clustering.

See http://www.mathworks.com/help/mdce/configure-cluster.html